# How can an animated object kept on the surface of an ocean?

Tags: animation, ocean-simulation

I tried to set the ocean as passive rigid body (collision mesh) and a boat as active rigid body.

The boat falls through the ocean. Which technique is recommended for this?

Ideally the boat would follow a curve and the physic simulation would calculate the orientation and level (z-axis).

Comment: Is it possible to turn the ocean into a solid object (such that the heaving surface is the top of a box) ? Will that help the physics system keep them from falling through?

Comment: You might try the *Shrinkwrap constraint*.

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks that was already half way.

Comment: @stacker I was originally thinking of the constraint, not the modifier, but it looks like the modifier works better (I didn't notice that the constraint doesn't take modifiers into account) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As gandalf3 suggested a [*Shrinkwrap constrained*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Shrinkwrap) works, but not alone. Using [Vertex Parent](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting#Vertex_Parent) on a triangle and shrinkwrap the triangle to the ocean does the trick.

[image]

[image]

For the second requirement to follow a curve a *Curve modifier* must be added before the Shrinkwrap in the modifier stack.

[image]

The vertex parent trick was described [here](http://gryllus.net/Blender/PDFTutorials/13A_NURBS_SailboatOnOcean/NURBS_Sailboat.pdf) but this tutorial uses softbodies and is more complicated to setup.