# How to have an object follow the surface of another object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a bunch of planes as one object I'm using to create a crowd of people on a hilly terrain. I'm looking for a way to snap all the "people" to the curvature of the terrain, without have to grab each one individually and raise or lower it.
[image: crowd following terrain]

I tried the shrinkwrap modifier, but it flattens them out, rather than keeping them upright. Is there a modifier for something like this? Something like a surface deform modifier. Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about using a Particle Emitter? You could Weight Paint the "hilly terrain" to control the density of the particles (people).

Comment: The density isn't the problem, it's making them follow the height of terrain I'm having troubles with.

Comment: You can use a Particle System.

Comment: I don't think the particle system isn't what I'm after. I'm also looking for a way to have fencing follow the terrain as well. You can see the fencing in the picture above.

Comment: You could use a "Lattice" but the planes/people wouldn't stay perpendicular to the surface of the terrain.

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10831/how-can-an-animated-object-kept-on-the-surface-of-an-ocean and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26023/in-blender-3d-is-there-any-function-like-flow-along-surface-in-rhino-3d

Comment: A [shrinkwrap constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76577/935) will position the object origin and not squash the whole mesh.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Particle System. Use your terrain as the emitter and the people as either an Object or a Group (Set their Origin to the bottom).

Set the Start and End time to 1.

Under Velocity change "Normal" to zero.

[image]

Choose either Object or Group (You'll need to separate your planes in Edit Mode press "P" and select Loose Parts). "Object" would be choosing one plane/person as the particle. With "Group" you could choose any number of planes/people for more variety (Select the planes in Object Mode and press CTRL +"G" to Group them).

[image]
[image]

Additionally you can have control over the Particle Systems density by Weight Painting and a Vertex Group. With your Emitter selected go into Weight Paint Mode and select an Add Brush (There also is a Subtract Brush).

[image]

[image]

Preform your Weight Painting. Blue represents the most density and red the least. Colors in between vary the density. This creates a Vertex Group with the default name "Group".

[image]

Go back to the Particle Emitter and under Vertex Groups > Density select or enter the name "Group".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the help. So I set the terrain up as the emitter, but I guess I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some additional info. Ask if you need more...

Comment: Oh thanks, I see that now. However, that's just creating more particles rather than moving the existing ones.

Comment: Yes, it's a work around...

Comment: Well, I appreciate the help because I will be able to use this technique in the future, however I'm looking for a way to deform the existing object at the moment. I wonder if I can't use physics and animate them falling until they just collide with the terrain?